# read bipartite graphs and one mode projection

Tags: r, igraph

How can I read a bipartite graph?
I tried the following code, but when I tried to make OMP, it says

```
Error in bipartite.projection(g, types = NULL) : 
  Not a bipartite graph, supply `types' argument
```

here is the code :

```
edgelist = read.csv("g1.csv",header=FALSE,sep=",")
g  = graph.edgelist(as.matrix(edgelist),directed=FALSE)
proj <- bipartite.projection(g,types=NULL)
g2= proj[[1]]
myplot(g2)
```

> g1.csv 1,5 1,4 2,4 3,5

Comment: if `set_vertex_attr` does not quite work, use this: https://rpubs.com/pjmurphy/317838 by Phil Murphy & Brendan Knapp . In case link is down: `V(g)$type <- bipartite_mapping(g)$type  ## Add the "type" attribute to the network.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the docs:

```
 Bipartite graphs have a ‘type’ vertex attribute in igraph, this is
 boolean and ‘FALSE’ for the vertices of the first kind and ‘TRUE’
 for vertices of the second kind.
```

So please add a `type` vertex attribute, that defines which vertices are in which group.